# How can I scale down AWS EC2 and RDS instances

Tags: amazon-web-services

I've been using AWS for a simple webapp for some time. I've noticed the costs are way too high for the app's usage:

- `EC2 t2.micro` : $28/mo
- `LoadBalancer-hour (or partial hour)`: $37
- `RDS db.m1.small instance hour (or partial hour) running MySQL`: $50

$100+/mo all for a site that has 5-10 users a day.

How can I scale down my existing EC2 and RDS instances and remove or reduce load balancing needs without redoing the work of setting all of that up?

---

Basically, I need to accomplish these things:

- Serve my frontend static app (in S3 currently) over HTTPS (currently using Cloudfront to do so)
- Serve my backend API (in ElasticBeanstalk currently) over HTTPS (I was told I need load balancing for this)
- Host a database (currently using AWS RDS with ElasticBeanstalk)
- There aren't many users currently, so I need much cheaper API hosting than $80+ a month for RDS and EC2. Need these services to be more around $30 total/mo. I don't see the need at all for load balancing, but like I mentioned, I thought I needed this for https?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need ELB or RDS. Note that ELB provides some security, protecting against some layer 4 and 7 attacks. You might choose to use CloudFlare (free) or CloudFront (cheap) to replace ELB, or you could go without. It's cheap security, and it offloads work from your server.

I run Nginx, PHP 5.6, and MySQL on a t2.nano. In the past 24 hours I've had 1500 users and 15,000 requests to around 15 websites. Some static resources were cached by the CDN, but all pages hit the server. The server uses about 2% of CPU according to CloudWatch, the average rarely climbs higher than that over a 5 minute period.

I have [a tutorial](https://www.photographerstechsupport.com/tutorials/hosting-wordpress-on-aws-tutorial-pt1-introduction-configuration-downloads/) on how I set this all up.

Key things I did are:

- Use the Nginx page cache for anonymous users
- Turn off MySQL performance schema (that's at the end of my [migration article](https://www.photographerstechsupport.com/tutorials/rds-to-ec2-migration-mysql/))
- Add 512MB of [swap space](https://www.photographerstechsupport.com/tutorials/adding-swap-space-ec2-amazon-linux-instance/) (it doesn't use much of it).
- Let's Encrypt for https, using [acmetool](https://github.com/hlandau/acme)

**Migration**

The best way to migrate MySQL is to use mysqldump. Set up MySQL on your server and configure it for low RAM, add a page file, dump the database from RDS into a file on your server, then upload the database to your serve. You'll probably need to set users and permissions up again. Do a final manual snapshot of your RDS database, then turn RDS off. In a few months go back and delete your RDS snapshot if all is well.

To change the size of your EC2 instance stop it, right click and change instance size, then start it again. It takes a minute or two. You can do it via the API if you want to.

**Answers to Questions**

*HTTPS*: "it seems like in order to have https with AWS, I need load balancers for my EC2 instances"

There are many ways to add https to EC2 servers.

1. Using an ELB with Amazon certificates is easy.
2. Request a certificate from a certificate authority (there are many) and configure your web server to use it. I have a tutorial on how to do that with free let's encrypt certificates and nginx [here](https://www.photographerstechsupport.com/tutorials/hosting-wordpress-on-aws-tutorial-part-5-free-https-https2-for-wordpress-using-lets-encrypt-aws/).
3. Use [CloudFlare](https://www.cloudflare.com/), which can proxy your http server via https. You can also use CloudFront to [proxy https back to http](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/HTTPandHTTPSRequests.html). I have no doubt there are many other ways

Note that if you have your domain configure to route traffic to an ELB you'll need to change things a bit. The easiest way is likely to be getting an elastic IP address for your EC2 instance and putting that elastic IP into your DNS configuration, as an A record.

*Instance Size*: I can't give you a concrete answer here as we don't have enough information. Changing from t2.micro to t2.nano should be easy since they're the same technology, just smaller.

If you were moving from another instance type I'd say check your AMI, maybe it's an old PV AMI rather than a newer HVM AMI. If you edit your question to give more information I can have another think about it.

Comment: Hi Tim, it seems like in order to have `https` with AWS, I need load balancers for my EC2 instances? Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: Also, I have load balancers and cloudfront for `https`, so when I right clicked and changed my EC2 instance size, it removed the EC2 instance from the LB and gave me error `Error starting instances: The requested configuration is currently not supported. Please check the documentation for supported configurations.`

Comment: I've answered your question in an edit to my answer

Comment: I wonder if, for my requirements, digital ocean may be the cheaper way to go

Comment: Sorry but we can't teach you how to use AWS or guide you through this entire process. If you want that level of help you need to hire someone. You've asked a question, you've gotten an answer. Now you need to go away, consider the answers, learn some more about AWS, and make any required changes. If you get stuck your first thing to do is Google it, after a while of effort (which will be a great way to learn) you could ask a new question here on SF. Suggest you accept the most useful answer.

Comment: Digital Ocean can be cheaper for simple use cases. If you need to scale up and need to migrate back to AWS that's more hassle. An AWS reserved instance can save cost. a t2.nano is very cheap. DO bandwidth is quite a bit cheaper than AWS. AWS free tier is great.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57179/discussion-between-growler-and-tim).

Answer (score 1):

A few options to consider -

1. Downgrading your EC2 instance to `t2.nano`
2. As your application do not have traffic/load you can simply stop using
   ELB
3. I think your RDS `db.m1.small` instance is set up with `multi-az` option
   enabled, you can modify the same and disable `multi-az` option as it
   will reduce your RDS instance cost to half of its current cost.

If you still want to reduce cost, you can consider EC2 [spot instances](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-spot-instances.html) or [reserved instances](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/reserved-instances/) for EC2 and RDS if that suits your need.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that spot instances can be terminated at any time, which is why they're so cheap.

Answer (score 1):

You can opt to reduce the size of your EC2 instance to **t2.nano** since you are not expecting that much traffic.

You can also stop using your Load Balancer. I don't think it serves any purpose here in terms of regulating incoming traffic.

You can also reduce your RDS to **db.t2.micro**. I spend around $20 on an RDS with this size. Also don't use Multi-AZ.

Although it needs more work, you can also opt to run a **t2.micro** EC2 and setup MySQL there yourself and stop using RDS completely.

Comment: Can I do all this with the current instances of EC2, RDS, etc or do I need to terminate those environments first and then start from scratch?

Comment: You don't need to terminate the EC2. Just Stop it and adjust the instance type.  To do this, go to Actions then select Change Instance Type. For RDS, go to Instance Action then select Modify.

Comment: I stopped my EC2 instance, changed from t2.micro to t2.nano. When I tried to restart, I got error `Error starting instances: The requested configuration is currently not supported. Please check the documentation for supported configurations.`

Comment: also, if I don't use load balancer, can I still get https?

Comment: You can use Let's Encrypt on your EC2 for HTTPS.